# What does MaskStore do behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, assembly, intel, intrinsics, avx2

my main programming language is C# and lately I've been trying to learn about vector programming and some simd instructions on the intel x86 axv2 for self-learning purposes. I came across the instruction [MaskStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.avx2.maskstore?view=net-6.0#system-runtime-intrinsics-x86-avx2-maskstore(system-int32*-system-runtime-intrinsics-vector256((system-int32))-system-runtime-intrinsics-vector256((system-int32)))) which maps to the axv2 instruction:

```
VPMASKMOVD m256, ymm, ymm
```

I'm just wondering how does this instruction work behind the scenes, programmatically in pseudo code is it something like:

```
for n in vector.values
    if (highest bit of mask is set for vector n)
    {
        address = source vector[n]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct.

The asm manual https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vmaskmov#vmaskmovpd---256-bit-store documents it with pseudo-code like that.  Intel's C/C++ intrinsics guide has less detailed but similar documentation: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,Other&ig_expand=5420,5420,5623,5626,7359,5403,5039&text=maskmov.

Note that it's an AVX1 instruction, not AVX2.  Supported since Sandybridge on Intel, AMD since Bulldozer.

Not very efficiently on AMD CPUs, though as per https://uops.info/ testing data.  Masked stores aren't easy to emulate, unlike maskload which can just do a regular load and then mask, only needing special hardware and/or a microcode assist if it has to do fault suppression when a masked-out part of the load would touch an unmapped page.

On Intel, masked stores are also first-class operations, only 3 uops for memory-destination `vmaskmovpd mem, ymm, ymm` on Intel since Skylake (p0 + p23+p4), down from 4 in Sandybridge/Haswell (p0+p1 + p23+p4)

Probably not a coincidence that Skylake has AVX-512 hardware, even though it's not enabled/exposed in the "client" chips; perhaps internally works as a compare-into-mask uop, and then a native masked-store uop.  Without micro-fusion of store-address and store-data, that's 3 uops total.  The ALU uop can only run on port-0 on Skylake, the same port required by [`vpmovq2m k, ymm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovb2m:vpmovw2m:vpmovd2m:vpmovq2m), unlike `vptestmq k, ymm,ymm`, so we can infer that it probably uses a uop like `vpmovq2m` to generate the internal mask-register value from the mask vector operand.

On AMD Zen2, mask load is single-uop (much improved over Zen1), but mask store is still 10 or 19 uops for XMM or YMM vector width, respectively.  4c or 6c throughput, so much slower than load / AND or blend / store if you can safely do a non-atomic RMW.  (Including a load/store of elements you don't modify.)

---

Maskmove has some use-case corner cases that can be disastrous, like taking a microcode assist on every instruction if used with an all-false mask on a read-only page.

That can happen if a page of memory hasn't been dirties yet and is still copy-on-write mapped so it's actually read-only as far as HW is concerned (in the page tables).  And then if you loop over it using load / compare / maskstore to conditionally replace some values or something, you might never dirty the page if no values need replacing, so multiple instructions take a slow microcode assist.

But OTOH, it can be a bit faster than store/mask/reload on Skylake for the same array-replacement task if you don't hit that bad case.

Comment: Thanks so much for such a detailed answer! I actually read through some of the intel docs but here's a follow up question, what does the `colon` mean when its something like: 

IF (SRC1[31]) DEST[31:0]←SRC2[31:0] - what does [31:0] mean in this case?

Comment: What's the recommended way of solving that COW issue? Maybe add ```*((volatile char*) x) = *((volatile char*) x)``` every 4 kiB to break the COW mapping? But that load-store forwarding is bothersome.

Comment: @fancycoconut: Those are bit-ranges.  `SRC1[31]` is the top bit of the low 32 bit element of that operand, `DEST[31:0]` is the whole low element.  So you're looking at the operation section for `vmaskmovps` (packed single) not `pd` (packed double).  Intel's PDF manual has an earlier section on how to read the entries; https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ is just a 3rd-party scrape of the instruction entries in the PDF, specifically Intel's vol.2 SDM.  And of course there's a plain English description section in each instruction entry.

Comment: @Homer512: If it's safe to store an unmodified element (like `dst[i] = condition ? dst[i] : other` rather than `if(cond) dst[i] = other;`), and this was an actual problem (all-empty masks being common), probably just load/blend/store and don't maskstore at all.  Especially if you care about performance on AMD.  One of the reasons for using maskstore is when you can't invent stores, e.g. when auto-vectorizing.  Compilers can't violate thread safety guarantees; for all they know, another thread is writing an element this one didn't.  Unlikely for an array, plausible for a single struct.

Comment: @Homer512: When maskstore is faster than blend/store, it's not by much.  For cases where you run into microcode-assist slowdowns, if you still want to use maskstore, the best workaround depends strongly on the use-case and details, and would be a separate question.  Store once per 4k wouldn't be good BTW; you might have started half way through a 4k page so you'd suffer microcode assists for the first half of the next page.  So you'd want to check for a page crossing.